# fabric.js - get New Height after redimensioning

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I create group with:

```
var text    = new fabric.Text(textValue,{left: 20, top: 30, fontSize:25});
var rect    = new fabric.Rect({
                    width       : text.get('width') + 40,
                    fill        : "#FFFFFF",
                    height      : 100,
                    stroke      : '#000000',
                    strokeWidth : 1

                  });

    var myGroupObj = new fabric.CustomGroup([  rect,text ], {
      left      : 0,
      top       : 0,
    });
```

Now whene I manually resizes my group and I want to get a new heigth.

```
myGroupObj.get('height')
```

I have always last one (100).
Somme idea to get new height, please?

Comment: Please forgive my bad english.

Comment: Its better if you can create jsbin for it.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/islyoung2/7Tf22/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of accessing the `.height` attribute, you should call the `getHeight()` function, which gives you the **actual** height (the one you see on the screen) of a fabric.js object. In the code you have created on jsfiddle, to get the real height, you should change the line `alert(activeObject.height);` by `alert(activeObject.getHeight());` and you will see the difference.

Cheers,
Gonzalo Gabriel

Comment: Thank you, I found a longer way to get it see my answer.

Comment: In new versions, it is `getScaledWidth()` as it says the docs http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#getScaledWidth

Answer (score 3):

I find solution to get New Height of object after manually resizes http://jsfiddle.net/islyoung2/7Tf22/4/.

```
var newHeight = myGroupObj.get('height') * myGroupObj.get('scaleY')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the new width or the new height, don't forget to update also `scaleX` and `scaleY`:

```
canvas.on("object:modified", function (e) {
    var activeObject = e.target;
        if (!activeObject) {
            return;
    }
    var newWidth = activeObject.width * activeObject.scaleX ;
    var newHeight = activeObject.height * activeObject.scaleY ;

    activeObject.width = newWidth;
    activeObject.height = newHeight;

    activeObject.scaleX = 1;
    activeObject.scaleY = 1;                
});
```